# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' error faced

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing this problem while coding;

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel(r'F:\Downloads\Book1.xlsx', index_col=0)
data.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
data['Time'] = data.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: you have to convert the index to datetime for using strftime method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parse_dates` argument in your `read_excel()` call, and this means pandas should convert the specified column to datetime objects:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel(r'F:\Downloads\Book1.xlsx', index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
data.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
data['Time'] = data.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

The documentation for `read_excel` is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `pd.to_datetime()` function to get `datetime` as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel(r'F:\Downloads\Book1.xlsx', index_col=0)
data.replace('NoData', np.nan, inplace= True)
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format="%H:%M")
```

You can check the `pandas` documentation for further information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime).